# Excel: parse text as formula

Tags: excel, excel-2003, excel-formula

I would like to have part of an excel formula be dynamic, other than a cell reference.

For instance, suppose that in column A (cells A1:A99) I have a bunch of numbers, and I want to know how many of those numbers are greater than 50.

If I wanted this calculation to be static, I could simply use one of the following:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$99,">50")
=SUM(IF($A$1:$A$99>50,1,0))
=SUM(($A$1:$A$99>50)*1)
```

I mention all three because my actual formula is hairy and a bit of a mix of the second and the third.  (After all, perhaps something will work with COUNTIF but not with the others.)

Now, I want to be able to type my condition in another cell (say C1).  So if I type ">50" in C1, my calculation will be as above, but if I type "<100" I will count how many entries of column A are less than 100.

Is this possible?  (I am using Excel 2003 on Windows XP.)

Answer (score 1):

There may be something that I'm missing. 
If you give

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$99,C1)
```

in any cell, and then in cell C1 you type >50 or <100 
don't you get what you want?

Comment: Hm, you are right.

I was hoping to find something I could use with my existing format (starting with `SUM`), rather than switch to `COUNTIF` or `SUMIF`.  But I think I can make it work with `SUMIF`.  So thank you for pointing out the obvious, which I missed.

Comment: I remember why I didn't want to use `COUNTIF` or `SUMIF`: In actuality I need multiple condition, based on more than just the cells I want to count.

For instance, say the numbers in question are in B1:B99, and in the A column are dates.  I will want to how many of the numbers in column B are >50 for which the date in column A is in a specific range, or on a Monday.

It appears that Excel 2007 has a built-in function `SUMIFS` to deal with this, but I have 2003.

Comment: then you could use something like 
SUMPRODUCT((A1:A99="a")*(B1:B99="b"))

Comment: Yes, but can I make that equal sign be dynamic?  I'm happy to have an `(A1:A99="Monday")` in there (and yes, `"Monday"` can be dynamic), but how to make `="b"` be dynamic, so I could set it to `>50` or `=500` by changing an outside cell.

Answer (score 1):

Use `INDIRECT`

```
=INDIRECT(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$99,">50"))
```

is same as

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$99,">50")
```

But, as you identified, the former, you can generate within the excel cells! I do it all the time, [for such things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266569/whats-the-first-program-you-wrote-that-you-were-proud-of/1139275#1139275).

Comment: becomingGuru, this looks promising, but Excel gives me a `#REF!` error when I try it.  When I trace the calculation steps, the final one before an error is `INDIRECT(6)` and then it (correctly) tells me that 6 isn't a valid reference.  How to fix?

Comment: Well, 6 obviously isn't a valid reference, so concatenate('A',6) to get A6 :)

Comment: I mean that 6 is the output of the COUNTIF function (specifically, how many entries in column A are greater than 50), which you suggested should become the input to indirect.  Can you clarify what should be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I usually solve this by adding another column carrying the result of a complex logical expression, like

```
=AND(OR(C3<D3;E3>=100);A3=VLOOKUP(B3;Sheet2!$A$2:$B$212;2;FALSE))
```

this formula is in all rows of -say- column F - note: no IF needed here!

then I calculate a complex conditional sum across column E using =SUMIF() like

```
=SUMIF(F2:F57;TRUE;E2:E57)
```

I know that some users say "I do not want to change my design. That's ok; my argument is that I have better control over the condition, I can work on the condition seperately from summing up or other functions that rely on that condition, and I can filter records for TRUE or FALSE to look at the subsets and have a rapid overview if the formula makes sense

hope that helps Good luck MikeD