# Excel: How to parse/cast text as a formula?

Tags: excel, parsing, casting

Is it possible to parse/cast text (like "=A1+A2") as a formula in MS Excel? I want to build a formula from pieces of text - some of which will only be typed in later by a user.

If the INDIRECT() function did not only work for referencing cells, then I could have typed this =INDIRECT("=A1+A2").

I know you can a work around this problem by simply adding a lot more hidden columns to do sub calculations. But for the sake scalability and efficiency, I would rather do something like the above.

I found a similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276821/excel-parse-text-as-formula) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001128/use-cell-text-to-build-excel-formula), yet they don't solve my problem.

---

## The Real-world problem:

*Read on for a better understanding as to why you would want to do the above*

#### Scenario

Each item in the list consists of a string, which contains anywhere from 1 to 5 account names each. Each account name is followed by an account number in brackets. The length of the number determines the type of account. Part of the account number is a date, of which the date format depends on the type of account. Further more, each account type may have more that 1 account-number length associated with it, although each number-length[*] is only associated with 1 account type.

#### Objectives

- Extract account-names and their respective account-numbers and account-types from a list.
- Make an assumption as to the account-type from the account-number
- Validate this assumption by inspecting the build of the number and elements in the name
- Check the validity of the account-numbers depending on their type.

***The tricky part**  (this is where my problem lies)
The account-types and their respective account-number-lengths are not known before hand, and are typed into a table by the user of the sheet, specifying a type of account and the number-lengths associated with this account-type. The user should type this into a list - not go and tinker around with delicate formulas*

#### Done so far

- Column A: Contains the raw data (each cell has up to 5 names and numbers)
- Columns B..F: Each column extracts 1 name, remains empty if all are already extracted
- Columns G..K: Each column extracts 1 number corresponding to its name in columns B..F, remains empty if all are already extracted
- Columns L..P: Each column calculates the length of the corresponding number in columns
  G..K

Now the user would type the following details into a table which assigns certain number-lengths an account type:
*TYPE2, BUSINESS, (OR(length=13,length=6))*
where *length* will later be replaced with the cell address which contains the calculated account number-length.

#### What I want to do now

Columns Q..U:
Should all indicate the account-type of the corresponding account-number in columns G..K. The idea is to build a nested if-elseIf-elseIf formula using the criteria typed in by the user as specified above. Example of one of the elseIF statements:
SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE("=IF(",*criteria*,",",*type*,",",*errCode*)),"length","O10"))
All of these elseIf statements will then be concatenated together to form a master formula which will then need to be parsed/cast as a formula to calculate the account-type

This proposal uses only 5 columns (1 for each account-number, containing the master formula) and a table specifying account-types and criteria, also keeping the user away from formulas. Editing 1 line of code (the criteria) will update all formulas. Efficient & Scalable.

Since the user should never tinker around with the formulas under the hood, a simple 1 column if-elseIf-elseIf is out of the question. The alternative to the above would be to make a separate column to test for each account-type for each account-number. Separating/Abstracting out each test to its own column results in much better readability, easier editing & much less debugging - Unless you like multi-screen-wide-formulas. Example: 5 account-numbers * 10 possible account types = 50 extra columns.
Each edit to any criteria needs to copied to 4 other non-adjacent columns and drag-filled down 10,000 rows (columns can not be adjacent since it is effectively a 5x5 array of columns). Not Efficient nor scalable. Unless I'm missing some elegant way of updating non-adjacent formulas in a single click

The rest of the validations error indications are trivial.

#### Sample data

Tshepo Trust (6901/2005) Marlene Mead (8602250646085)
Great Force Inv 67 Pty Ltd (200602258007)
Jane (870811) Livingstone (6901/2005) Janette Appel (8503250647056) James (900111)

---

I know all this would probably be much easier to achieve with clever usage of VBA, eliminating all the need to simulate abstraction, encapsulation, multi-dimensional arrays and functional programming on a spreadsheet. But until I can program in VBA, worksheet formulas will be my refuge.

[*]: account number-length could also be described as the amount of digits in the number or as indicated by this formula: *LEN(accNumber)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA you have access to Cell.Formula.
I usually used Range to peek a cell by address.

Comment: Yes that would have worked perfectly - though I only saw your answer today (almost 4 years later) Thank you.

Up to that point I only used in-cell formulas - but at that time I had to take the dive into vba macros - which solved a whole lot of problems for me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would answer your question(it's a very detailed question!), but if your user was entering the account numbers in a table (I'm calling it 'RefTable') , that was:

```
Length of account number | business type
----------------------------------------
             6           |  Accountant
             8           |  Advisor
```

Then you could just use a vlookup on the length of the account number, given you've already separated them out.

```
=vlookup(len(accNumber), Reftable, 2, false)
```

Make sure that you either use a dynamic range name, or specify plenty of space below in RefTable, so that when your users add types, they don't get lost.

Also, if you have two different accounts with the same length, this could get you into trouble.